# How to access a Symfony service that is used by a client request in a web test case?

Tags: symfony

I have an application that relies on third party services. In order to make sure that the application works properly, I want to mock the third party services and make sure that the application is working as expected.

This requires that I am able to configure the mock services before creating the requests. However, I am unable to do so.

Consider the following code:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
//..

class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testSignupLink()
    {
        $container = static::createClient()->getContainer();

        // This returns a different instance from the one used by the client request
        $service = $container->get('third-party-service');
        $service->setErrorState(MockService::SOME_ERROR_STATE);
        // ...

        // The request creates a new instance of the $service internally which doesn't have the error state that was set above
        $client->request('POST', '/abc/1');
    }
}
```

The 'abc' controller relies on a service that I can't access. When I access the service from the container, I get a different instance from the one that  is used by the client request.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Need more details concerning what do you want to do

Comment: I added more details about what I am trying to do. Let me know if you require additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood you, here is what you need:
https://github.com/PolishSymfonyCommunity/SymfonyMockerContainer